# Distance Correlation

Tags: performance-tuning, probability-or-statistics

I am interested in calculating the [distance correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_correlation) between a pair of vectors. To do it I use `CorrelationDistance` function, but I get a distance greater than 1.  One of the of the properties of this distance that is limited between 0 and 1. I am using a correct function, or I did miss something?

```
CorrelationDistance[RandomReal[5, 100], RandomReal[5, 100]]
```

Comment: Where did you get that the distance should be between $0$ and $1$? Recall that the correlation distance is effectively computed as $1-\cos(\text{something})$, which can take values in $[0, 2]$.

Comment: @J.M. Please take a look for the first property in the Wikipedia link

Comment: The Wikipedia article is about distance correlation, not about correlation distance...

Comment: Ok... anyway I am interested in calculate distance covariance. If it is possible to use one of WL distances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, the distance correlation can be computed as follows:

```
DistanceCorrelation[X_, Y_] := Module[{A, B, n, w},
 n = Length[X];
 w = ConstantArray[1./n, {n}];
 Module[{x, y},
  A = DistanceMatrix[X];
  x = A.w;
  y = Subtract[0.5 (x.w), x];
  A += (Outer[Plus, y, y]);
  B = DistanceMatrix[Y];
  x = B.w;
  y = Subtract[0.5 (x.w), x];
  B += (Outer[Plus, y, y]);
  ];

 Sqrt[
   Total[A B, 2]/Sqrt[Total[A^2, 2] Total[B^2, 2]]
   ]
 ]
```

Example:

```
X = RandomReal[5, 100];
Y = RandomReal[5, 100];
DistanceCorrelation[X, Y]
```

## Edit

The Wikipedia article is very confusing. I am not sure whether the overall square root over the result should be there or not.

Comment: Hmm, why not use e.g. `x = Mean[A]`, since it computes means of columns directly?

Comment: Good point. I changed it.

Comment: In the meantime, I replaced `Mean` by a `Dot` for performance reasons.

Comment: Oh yeah, that is nicer...